# Игнорирование "Missing a Javadoc comment" в IntellijIdea Checkstyle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, плагин, javadoc

Какое правило в `sun_checks.xml` нужно добавить, чтобы игнорировалaсь ошибка

> Missing a javadoc comment

в `Checkstyle`?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как в checkstyle-idea, но для maven-checkstyle-plugin я создавал файл checkstyle-suppressions.xml с содержимым

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
     "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.0//EN"
     "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_0.dtd">

<suppressions>
  <suppress checks="JavadocPackage"
    files="."/>
  <suppress checks="JavadocType"
    files="."/>
  <suppress checks="JavadocMethod"
    files="."/>
  <suppress checks="JavadocVariable"
    files="."/>
</suppressions>
```

Уверен, что в настройках плагина можно указать расположение такого файла и без редактирования sun_checks.xml.